# Autofill from active cell to 26 columns across

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell with a formula. I want to autofill from that cell, to a fixed number of columns across.

I am trying something along the lines of this:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("RC:RC[+26]"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

but can't get it right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Offset` inside a `Range` command:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=range(activecell, activecell.Offset(0,26)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

The RC style is used in formulas, but I have never seen it used inside a `Range` object.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Resize`:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A2").Resize(, 26), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With
```

This will fill the formula from A2:Z2.